# My Ubuntu server has a default route in an Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

My Ubuntu server has a default route that I can't find in any file

Typing in:

```
ip route
```

Returns:

```
default via 192.168.1.100 dev ens18 src 192.168.1.153 metric 202
```

But I can't find this .100 IP in any file anywhere.

And this command:

```
nmcli con show
```

Doesn't list anything at all.

Comment: If it receives an IP address through DHCP then the default gateway is obtained through DHCP as well. It's not saved to any file.

Comment: It's not on DHCP. My router is my DHCP server and my gateway. It's also 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Check /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/network/interfaces.d/

Answer (score 1):

I threw in the towel and starting randomly grepping directories.
It was in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

I was making new files in `/etc/network`, I was editing the Netplan yaml out of desperation.

Hopefully this helps others. I was about ready to reload the OS or create some of virtual router proxy at the bad IP address!